# wordpress header leaks into body in a specific template

Tags: page-template, headers, get-template-part

very strange problem, that happens only in one specific template. part of the  part "leaks" into the  tag - and I can't figure out why.

the "header.php" code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="he">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"  content="IT=edge,chrome=IE8">
  <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?> <?php } ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
  <meta name="generator" content="WordPress <?php bloginfo('version'); ?>" /> <!-- leave this for stats -->
  <!-- the site meta data for search-->
  <meta name="description" content="****" /> 
  <meta name="keywords" content="****" />
  <!--end of meta data-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
  <link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" title="RSS .92" href="<?php bloginfo('rss_url'); ?>" />
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Atom 0.3" href="<?php bloginfo('atom_url'); ?>" />
  <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
  <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&format=link'); ?>
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
  <!--IE specific bugs some of this doesn't work yet -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
      behavior:url("<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/csshover3.htc");
    }

    #booklist li:hover {
              -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
              -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
              box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
              behavior:url("<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/PIE.php");

    }
  </style>

  <![endif]-->
<!--google analytics code-->
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-****-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
<!--end of google analytics code-->

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

<header>
<div id="header">
<!-- בשביל להחזיר את הכותרת ותיאור הבלוג לכאן להוריד את סימן ההערה מהhtml
    <h1><a href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
    <h2><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h2>
-->
</div> 

<nav id="menu">
<ul>
    <li style="zoom:1" class="<?php if (is_home()) { ?>current_page_item<?php } else { ?>page_item<?php } ?>"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="Home">ראשי</a></li>
    <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1'); ?>
</ul>
<!--<div id="menu"></div>-->
</nav>
</header>
```

the template code (the relevant part):

```
   <!--?php /* Template Name: bookstore*/ ?-->
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<div id="content">


    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

<!-- בשביל להחזיר את שם העמוד צריך לבטל את סימן ההערה ב# -->
        <h2><?php #the_title(); ?></h2>
            <div class="entry">
<!--<h1 style="text-align: center; ">
<strong>
</strong>
</h1>-->                <?php the_content('<p>Continue reading &raquo;</p>'); ?>

                <?php //if page is split into more than one
                    link_pages('<p>Pages: ', '</p>', 'number'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
      <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<div class="entry">
```

the leaking part is everthing after the link rel="prev"

be glad for any help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be a little more specific on which part is 'leaking' into the body? It's hard to tell without running any code and having other parts of the theme to look at.

Comment: actually I can't recreate this - I saw it using ie developer toolbar and with firebug in other browsers - but the source code look alright - so - whatever.. probably a bug the way those tools render a page

Answer (score 0):

Please change the character encoding to UTF-8 without BOM. I had the same issue and fixed it.